# Converting vertical datum of Lowest Astronomical Tide (LAT) to EGM96

Tags: dem, datum, bathymetry, sea-level-rise, egm96

I want to model the impact of sea level rise (SLR) on the coast zone of an Asian country using a modified bathtub model. The SLR projections include AR6 results and extreme sea level (ESL) by high tide water level and storm surges.

The DEM dataset I use is CoastalDEM, whose vertical datum is EGM96. The present-day tidal elevations along the coastline are obtained from [FES2014](https://www.aviso.altimetry.fr/en/data/products/auxiliaryproducts/global-tide-fes.html), and its highest astronomical tide (HAT) data is referenced to Lowest Astronomical Tide (LAT), according to the [reference](https://os.copernicus.org/articles/17/615/2021/#section6):

> **Lowest astronomical tides are commonly used in hydrographic services as the reference level for nautical charts and terrain models.** It is also a valuable parameter in maritime engineering and risk assessment studies. The FES2014b LAT (and HAT, highest astronomical tide) chart has been computed from an 20-year tidal prediction (to account for nodal fluctuation in tidal amplitudes) based on all available tidal constituents in the FES2014b atlas (Fig. 23)......

As I understand, the mean sea level (MSL) in EGM96 can be presented as zero, but the MSL in LAT-referenced dataset can be any positive value, but how can I convert the vertical datum of LAT to EGM96?

Also, how can I plus the ESL water level in a DEM data to model sea level rise?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.